# AHK open excel workbook and repair

Tags: excel, autohotkey, repair

hi can anyone help me with the below code, i have an excel sheet that i need to open and repair then save, i do this because it tends to break atlot. any help much appreciated

```
 ; Open the Excel document

xlApp := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")    ; create a (new) instance of Excel
xlApp.Visible := true                         ; make Excel visible
xlApp := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")    ; make Excel active 

xlApp := xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Phill\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx", CorruptLoad := XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile)
xlApp := ""   ; clear the variable
return
```

Comment: "it tends to break atlot" is not very specific. It would be useful for you to describe what happens exactly

Comment: my excel sheet jjsut randomly breaks and all my vba goes missing, i have no idea why so i always have to open it and repair, i just want it up open using auto hot keys but also repair it

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues here:

1. AHK doesn't support named parameters for COM
2. AHK doesn't know what XlCorruptLoad.xlRepairFile means

Solutions:

1. Based on the [AHK documentation](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/v1/lib/ComObjActive.htm), use commas with nothing between to send the value in the proper position for CorruptLoad. According to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.workbooks.open?view=excel-pia), it's the last of 15 parameters.
2. The value for [XlCorruptLoad](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.excel.xlcorruptload?view=excel-pia).xlRepairFile is 1, so that's what you'd pass in for that parameter.

Here is the full (untested) code:

```
 ; Open the Excel document
xlRepairFile:= 1

xlApp := ComObjCreate("Excel.Application")    ; create a (new) instance of Excel
xlApp.Visible := true                         ; make Excel visible
xlApp := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")    ; make Excel active 

xlApp := xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\Phill\Desktop\New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx", , , , , , , , , , , , , , xlRepairFile)
xlApp := ""   ; clear the variable
return
```